# vbscript autocomplete

Tags: vbscript, autocomplete

Does someone know where can i find a vbscript autocomplete, google style (no postback)?

Thanks

Comment: What on earth __is__ a "Vbscript autocomplete"?  Whats the host or context of your question?

Comment: If JS is not allowed, then you can try converting available autocomplete JS code to VBS.

Comment: Any tool that does this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're talking about intellisense?

There's intellisense in Visual Studio 2008 and it recognizes COM objects, for example, if you were to start typing the following:

```
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim f
Set f = fso.
```

The moment you press the fullstop (.) after fso it will "intelligently" lookup the definition "Scripting.FileSystemObject" and present you with a choice of methods and properties. If you continue typing "OpenTextFile(" it will "intelligently" lookup the parameters for you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently no one use VBScript as a client side scripting language, so you won't be able to find a VBScript autocomplete script anywhere on the Internet.

It is advisable to use JavaScript instead of VBScript, as only IE browsers support VBScript.

EDIT: If you take a [look at this](http://www.devx.com/devx/editorial/15821), you'll know where VBScript lies.

Comment: I can't use javascript. Huge organization. tuff rules.

Answer (score 0):

Test Design Studio is a very good IDE for VBScript development. Also you can try VBSEdit. I would highly recommend Test Design Studio, its a cool development tool for VBScript programmers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Vbsedit http://www.adersoft.com/

This has many features that will help you create, edit, debug your vbs files.
You can also use it to compile to EXE without unpacking to temporary folder.

To use autocomplete just press ALT + right arrow OR CTRL + Space, or Right click in the editing area and click complete word. OR click the 'Edit' button on the menu bar then click 'Complete Word'

Visit their website for more information.

Comment: Is it coincidence that both of your posts advertise whatever this Adersoft company is selling?

Comment: Not really, i just found two similar questions so i posted the same answer more or less.

Answer (score -2):

Try Notepad++ it works great for VBScript and many other things!

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: OP didn't ask for a code editor, he asked a question about a vbscript function

Comment: I did not see a question about a particular function in the post... But with the correct extensions notepad++ will help in VBS syntax.